# Кросс-доменный ajax-запрос для получения xml

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-origin, cross-domain

Всем привет.

Некий сервер отдаёт xml-файл, программа на другом домене должна с помощью ajax получить этот файл, однако не получает так как "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Повлиять на сервер с xml-файлом я не могу. Пользоваться proxy не хочу и вряд ли могу. Какие есть варианты решения задачки?

Comment: @Igor, отказать. В моём тексте написано явно: "Пользоваться proxy не хочу и вряд ли могу"

Comment: @norbornen любой удачный способ без изменения заголовков стороннего сайта, либо без прокси, будет  ошибкой в безопасности веб (в лучшем случае это критичный баг в реализации браузера).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существуют много методов различной степени костыльности без использования серверного прокси, не буду подробно перечислять их все.

1. iframe
2. flash
3. window.name
4. document.domain
5. HTML5 postMessage
6. CORS и XMLHTTPRequest 2
7. JSONP

Большинство из них так или иначе реализовано в js библиотеке [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/wp/). Также она подбирает нужный метод в зависимости от обстановки.

Comment: c xml есть нюансы?

Comment: Теоретически вообще не должно быть это ведь просто язык разметки, на практике маловероятно.