# Парсинг xml-документа на другом домене

Tags: xml, cross-domain

Ребята, нужна помощь, есть база данных, в xml формате, она на другом домене. Мне нужно из нее парсить цены. Я на javascript подключаюсь к ней с помощью XMLHttpRequest, но подключается только Internet Explorer, а остальные браузеры пишут что то подобное

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Кто нибудь знает как можно нормально кроссдоменно подключаться именно к xml?
Я пробовала еще через yql - но там xml - это запрещенный формат походу

Comment: [Кросс-доменный-ajax-запрос-для-получения-xml](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413353/Кросс-доменный-ajax-запрос-для-получения-xml)

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что ты пытаешь присоединиться с клиента с другому домену. К примеру, если человек сидит на сайте **http://ru.stackoverflow.com**, то он может обратится к ресурсу **https://ru.stackoverflow.com/otvet42**, а вот обращение к **http://www.starwars.com/databank/darth-vader** уже не пройдёт. Поэтому придётся либо использовать iframe, либо проксировать запросы через свой сервер. В HTML5 данная проблема решаема на стороне клиента. Расписывать подробно не буду, вот рецепты на русском:

- [HTML5](http://javascript.ru/ajax/cross-origin-2)
- [Не HTML5](http://javascript.ru/ajax/cross-domain-scripting)